# apex button to call a page in another application on another workspace?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a workspace with which I have 1 main applications . Now I want to have a main page from where I could call main pages of different  applications on different workspace. I used this syntax to call home page in another application but to no avail

```
 f?p=114:1:&APP_SESSION.
```

but always redirect to login page.

i am already change the Cookie Name in all application to same name "all_my_cookie" it's working fine  when the applications in same workspace  but not work when the applications in different workspace.

it possible to do that ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it works for applications in the same workspace, but not for applications in another workspace. Though, I might be wrong; wait for someone else's opinion.

Comment: That's correct. This is because APEX doesn't share session for applications on multiple workspaces. To accomplish this you should consider SSO (Single Sign-On) authentication scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, SSO is not implemented in my company and cant be used as I have internal and external users.